# Error with Lua "if then" statements ('end' expected (to close 'if' at line 28))

Tags: lua, computercraft

I got an error that says

> ```
> bios:14: [string "Lighting"]:58: 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 28)
> ```

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing since I'm new to Lua and coding in general. I assume that it has something to do with not having an `end` somewhere.

```
term.clear()
term.setCursorPos(17, 4)
print("Welcome")
sleep(2)
term.setCursorPos(8, 5)
print("What lights would you like to control?")
input = read()
if input == "Hall" then
  term.clear()
  term.setCursorPos(17,4)
  print("On or Off?")
  input = read()
  if input == "on" then
    redstone.setOutput("back", true)
    print("Hall Lighting Turned On")
    sleep(5)
    shell.run("Lighting")
  else
    redstone.setOutput("back", false)
    print("Hall Lighing Turned Off")
    sleep(5)
    shell.run("Lighting")
  if input == "Bedroom" then
  term.clear()
  term.setCursorPos(17,4)
  print("On or Off")
  input = read()
  if input == "on" then
    redstone.setOutput("left", true)
    print("Bedroom Lighting Turned On")
    sleep(5)
    shell.run("Lighting")
  else
    redstone.setOutput("left", false)
    print("Bedroom Lighing Turned Off")
    sleep(5)
    shell.run("Lighting")
  if input == "Labs" then
  term.clear()
  term.setCursorPos(17,4)
  print("On or Off?")
  input = read()
  if input == "on" then
    redstone.setOutput("right", true)
    print("Lab Lighting Turned On")
    sleep(5)
    shell.run("Lighting")
  else
    redstone.setOutput("right", false)
    print("Lab Lighing Turned Off")
    sleep(5)
    shell.run("Lighting")
  end
else
  print("Error")
  sleep(3)
  shell.run("Lighting")
end
```

Comment: You are missing quite a number of `end` statements for your `if` statements. Using indentation will **greatly** help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are missing `end` word in several places.

The structure should be like:

```
if ... then
  some code
else
  some optional code
end
```

Additionally, try to indent your code better. It will become clear to you where you should put `end` words then.

What you want is probably:

```
term.clear()
...
input = read()

if input == "Hall" then
  ...
  if input == "on" then
    ...
  else
    redstone.setOutput("back", false)

    shell.run("Lighting")
  end -- missing end!
end -- missing end!

if input == "Bedroom" then
    ...
  if input == "on" then
    ...
  else
    redstone.setOutput("left", false)
    ...
    shell.run("Lighting")
  end -- missing end!
end -- missing end!

...
```